# Where should I place my Unit Tests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

Using the [Test-driven development process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) with an iOS project, **where should I place the test logic?**

I have previously either put them directly into each implementation file, or in an auxiliary file per class - ie. petur.m is accompanied by peturTest.m - I feel this leads to bad structure so I wanted to hear how to do this properly.

Comment: To elaborate on _bad structure_; I have an idea of how to do things, as well as others on my team. The answer to the above question will be tied into the projects styling guide - which in turn will result in _good structure_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical strategy is to set up a separate target for your unit test code. 
You don't want to include your unit tests in your implementation files because that will just add to the size of the app that has to be installed. Also, you will frequently have testing code which can put objects into bad states or expose things that shouldn't be exposed for anyone's usage. You don't want someone on your team to accidentally use a unit testing method that they thought was the real method.

you can use apple's documentation to find out how to set up a testing target:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1

Once you have an extra target set up for your unit tests, all of your unit testing code will be included in this target, but not in the deliverable target. A typical pattern is to have 1 or more unit test classes for each testable class in your app. If you need to expose any additional functionality (expose methods or properties on an object for the purpose of setting up state variables etc.) then i recommend writing them as categories on your production classes.